# Why is super here referencing to the same address as referenced by reference variable sc1?

Tags: java, class, object, reference, super

Isn't super suppose to refer object of Object class type which is not created here?

```
   public class SuperChk
    {
        void test()
        {
            System.out.println(super.toString());
        }
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            SuperChk sc1 = new SuperChk();
            System.out.println(sc1);
            sc1.test();
        }
    }
```

Comment: there are lots of errors in this code..

Comment: I'm using this program to simply find out how does super keyword work. It is compiling and running successfully, but the fourth line is printing the address which is same as referenced by the reference variable sc1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Isn't super suppose to refer object of Object class type which is not created here?

Err ... no.

The `super` keyword (when used that way) says "want to refer to `this`, but viewed as an instance of its superclass".  It is the way that a subclass calls methods in a superclass that it may have overridden.

The `java.lang.Object` class is the ultimate superclass of all reference types, and your `SuperChk` class is no different.  Your `SuperChk` class has `toString()` method (inherited from `Object`) and `super.toString()` is calling it.

Now in your example, `super.` is redundant because `SuperChk` does not override String.  But here is an example where it is NOT redundant ...

```
public class SuperChk {
    private void test() {
        System.out.println(toString());
        System.out.println(super.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Hello world";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperChk sc1 = new SuperChk();
        sc1.test();
    }
}
```

If you compile and run that, you will see that `toString()` and `super.toString()` are calling different methods.

Comment: But I still don't get the answer to why super is pointing to the address of the current object?

Comment: The answer to that is *because the Java language specification **says** it does!*  Read JLS 15.11.2  - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2

Answer (score 0):

Every Java class inherits implicitly from `Object`. So you call the method `toString` defined by `Object` and inherited by your class.